# Problem with addιtion abstraction in Field Calculator

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, expression

I want a bit analytical respond for the mistakes I have done in my code cause I am new to programming. I am using *ArcGis 10.2.* and I must process a field with distances in an attribute table I have. Through my python code I am trying to put my field (MO) in a list so as to use it as list. But as much as I tried I didn't get anything.

My field **MO** is like: 2367 2356 2352 2347 2345 2337 2331 2304

---

And here is my code:

```
MO = [MOBIL]
L = len(MO) - 1
    MO[0] = MO[0] - 10
    for i in range(M):
    MO[i] = MO[i] - MO[i+1]
```

Comment: You need to use *.append()* on the list, not +=

Comment: So you want to sum the values in the MO field is that right?

Comment: @NathanW No, let's leave the last line, i just tried it in a python window to see if it works as script. I want only the differences in the MO, but the first value which will be abstracted must be minus 10.

Comment: @BritishSteel how exactly you mean that with .append(), because i have a big mess in my mind with ArcPy, although i have read "Programming ArcGis with Python Cookbook"

Comment: Can you post what you expect as output result.  That might be easier.

Comment: @NAthanW right away. to have in field MO: 1 4 5 2 8 6 for the values above

Comment: The way I understood your question was that you wanted to add elements to your list. In that case, when you have a list then you can use append to add elements to that list. For example: someList.append(aNewElement). But perhas I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @BritishSteel, almost. I want to substract from the first value 10, and afterwards to substract each value with the next, so as to have 1 4 5 2 8 6 for the values above

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way but this works:

```
MD = '2367 2356 2352 2347 2345 2337 2331 2304'
values = [int(v) for v in MD.split()]
first = values[0] - 10
values = values[1:]
values.insert(0, first)
[abs(values[i-1]-values[i]) for i in range(1,len(values) - 1)]
```

and if that version is a scary you can break it out so it's not as bad:

```
newvalues = []
for i in range(1, len(values) -1):
    last = values[i-1]
    current = values[i]
    diff = abs(last - current)
    newvalues.append(diff)
```

Comment: sorry the sum i wrote was by fault, i just tested my script in python window to see if it works. I want the difference of values, with the first value to be minus 10, all these as a script in code block in field calculator.

Comment: right away. to have in field MO: 1 4 5 2 8 6 for the values above

Comment: i didn't understand the MO. I must put as MO my column and put it as def in python code block? or as standalone script starting with import arcpy?

Comment: to describe better what i want: For these numbers 105 90 79 69 85, i want to create to a new column with these:           (105-10)-90, 90-79, 79-69, 69-85 with field calculator. That's all.